# PHP, GD library, Image rotation

Tags: php, image, rotation

I'm new to GD and I'm trying to build a simple script that rotates an image, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\uploading.php on line 6
```

Here is my php:

```
$imgsrc = 'uploaded/Tulips.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgsrc);
$imgRotated = imagerotate($img,45,-1);
imagejpeg($imgRotated,"uploaded/myPicRotated.jpg",100);
```

is there something wrong with this?

UPDATE : 
     I replaced -1 with 0 in `imagerotate($img,45,0)`and it works fine.
     However I get a black background color. How do I change it to be a white color?

Comment: I just tested this and it works perfectly. After `$img = imagecreatefromjpeg...` can you add `var_dump($img);`?

Comment: I tried var_dump($img) and here is the output : resource(3, gd)

Comment: How about `var_dump($imgRotated);`?

Comment: it returns false with -1 at the end, however when I put 0, it works fine and returns : resource(4, gd). The problem now is that I get a black background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If -1 doesn't work, put in 0 and you will get a black background.
In order to change the background to any other color, all you have to do use [imagecolorallocate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) and [imagefill()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php). In my case I want the background to be white, and here's the final code that worked for me:

```
$imgsrc = 'uploaded/Tulips.jpg';
    if (file_exists($imgsrc)) {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgsrc);
    if ($img !== false) {

    $imgRotated = imagerotate($img,45,0);
    
    $backgroundcolor = imagecolorallocate($imgRotated, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($imgRotated, 0, 0, $backgroundcolor);
    
    if ($imgRotated !== false) {
      imagejpeg($imgRotated,"uploaded/myPicRotated.jpg",100);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to thank [@Paul Giragossian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4007592/paul-giragossian) for the help.

Comment: I am using above given example: but I am getting error:  failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: First, you should activate GD library in your php configs.

Answer (score 0):

imagerotate has returned false because an error has occured (maybe $imgsrc doesn't exists ?)

Try to test $img before rotate :

```
$imgsrc = 'uploaded/Tulips.jpg';
if (file_exists($imgsrc)) {
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgsrc);
  if ($img !== false) {
    imagealphablending($img, true); 
    imagesavealpha($img, true); 
    $imgRotated = imagerotate($img,45,-1);
    if ($imgRotated !== false) {
      imagejpeg($imgRotated,"uploaded/myPicRotated.jpg",100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The image exists, but I still have the same issue.
What's surprising, when I replace -1 with 0 in imagerotate, it works fine, However the background is black.
I still don't understand why -1, which stands for a white background color doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this but the problem persists. There are two possibilites, either this one only works with png images or I have a problem with my php configuration.